# How to center a scrollable image with Flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout

I want to display an image in a viewport (Scaffold body:) such that the whole height is used, and the image is scrollable horizontally if needed. This works fine:

```
       SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: SizedBox(
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Image.file(aDog.image, fit: BoxFit.cover)))
```

BUT since the most interesting part of the image normally is in the middle of the image, I want the initial scroll be such that the image is centered horizontally.

I have tried wrapping SingleChildScrollView, SizedBox and Image.file with Center and Align widgets. Also tried wrapping Image.file with a Row widget. Nothing works.

The left part of the image is always what is shown initially.

Can this be done with Flutter?

UPDATE: Using a ScrollController, I can pre-scroll the image a fixed number of pixels. But this is not what I want. The images vary in size.